# How do you replace a letter with another letter on an input.value

Tags: javascript, html

So I ran into a problem here. I have an input, and a paragraph that will hold its value.

All nice and good. But, for example, I want to change the letter "a" let's say with "b". On every occurance. How do I do that? I only got to make it work one time on the first occurance like this:

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");

input.addEventListener("input", function(){
  h1.innerText = input.value.replace("a", "b");
 
});
```

```html
<input type="text">
<h1></h1>
```

How do I make it replace it on every occurance? And how do I make it replace *more* than one letter? Like, now if the user pressed the letter "b", replace it with "t" for example, besides the first replacement (a with b).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: You can pass a RegExp with global flag set to true to replace (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)). That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding an event listener to an input with "input" which is invalid. Valid events would be: click, keyup, etc...

Here is a pen that shows how to replace all a's with b's.

It uses a regular expression to find all [a] using /g for global string search and /i for case-insensitive and replacing them with "b". find: /[a]/gi  replace: "b"

```
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var h1 = document.querySelector("h1");

input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  h1.innerText = input.value.replace(/[a]/gi, "b");
});
```

https://codepen.io/jthomas077/pen/mGPbrB

Comment: Sorry but "input" is an actual event listener. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp

And I was just about to type "oh, I missed the '/gi' ". I'm really not that great at regex! Thanks for helping.

Comment: Interesting... never used "input" as an event lol. RegEx's can be mind-numbing lol.  This is a great regex tester/builder to play with: https://regex101.com/. No worries man!

Comment: Actually there's a problem.
So, I successfully replaced "a" with "b". But then if I want to replace "b" with "c" I will always get "c" even if I press "a".

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with your replacement logic?

Comment: I'm trying to make a "translator" to a language that I've invented. And a is going to be replaced with e, e with i, i with o etc, like, "person" would be "pirsun".